# Metal detector discrimination problem

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatic

I was experimenting with discriminating metal detector

I'm using TX coil about 28cm diameter, and 0.9mH with 470nF capacitor- pushing about 5Vpp sin wave from a signal generator

The RX coil also about 28 cm diameter and about 7.5mH, with 47nF capacitor it is going to a TIA and then into an oscilloscope.

Now when I'm moving a coin made of 25% Nickle and 75% brass - the receive coil creates a change of amplitude of about 2.5uA but no phase change

While a coin 92% brass, 6% aluminum , 2% Nickle there is no change Also for a gold ring - i didn't notice any change in amplitude/phase

Why the second coin / gold ring didn't make any effect?

[image: Setup]

this kind of TIA should have a gain of -200,000A/V and it clamps the negative part of the input since I don't have bipolar PSU just reaching the rail ground, I nulled the coils to about -0.5V amplitude from the TIA

when moving the coin above the coils the maximum change is about another -0.5V amplitude = 2.5uA change.

Edit: I tried today to put the TX coil under the RX coil - this improved the sensitivity and now I can see the phase shift for different metals -
Although the change is much more subtle then what I have seen on youtube videos where they use less precise tools and with smaller coils
what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Draw your receive circuit paying particular attention to the tuning and TIA connection. Presumably your coils overlap about 30%? Please talk about signal voltages from the TIA and explain what the null value was and what the peak value rose to when a coin was used.

Comment: Have you tested your system with a piece of iron?  Most metal detectors use a discrimination setting to reject iron (ferrous) bearing metals.

Comment: Hey Andy aka - i edited in the setup